# Algebraic group: Property of $f\in K[G]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group with product $\mu:G\times G\to G$ and identity $e$.

We know that for $f\in K[G]$ then for $x,y\in G$ we have $\mu^*f=\sum f_i\otimes g_i$ for $f(xy)=\sum f_i(x)g_i(y)$.

Why do we have the property that:
$$f=\sum g_i(e)f_i=\sum f_i(e)g_i?$$

I can't even interpret what this even means.

Extra tags: Humphreys - Linear Algebraic Groups - Page 71

Comment: If $f \in K[G]$ then what is $x,y$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 See edit - Oh right I had a typo too

Comment: Maybe they meant $f \in L^1(G)$ or $L^2(G)$

Comment: @user1952009 What are those? Is that a Lie group analog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self answer, since I just got it - poor textbook notation in my opinion, but:
$$f(x)=f(xe)=\sum f_i(x)g_i(e)$$ and $$f(x)=f(ex)=\sum f_i(e)g_i(x)$$

So $$f= \sum f_ig_i(e)=\sum f_i(e)g_i$$